# how to change xml attribute value in java through a database

Tags: java, xml

I have a database which contains relevant Id's for certain events. When i send a request to obtain a specific event's information (by sending the event id), I want that event's information to be manipulated onto an XML file.

For example; an event may be a tennis match; when I send the eventId, I would expect to see the players playing, current score, what set the game is on, the gender (males/females game) etc, and forward this information into an XML file.

Example XML format

```
<score t1="0" t2="0" type="match"/>
<score t1="0" t2="0" type="game"/>
<score t1="0" t2="0" type="set3"/>
<events><event stime="123456789"/></events>
<tournament id="65972" name="Sweden F6, Singles"/>
<category id="785" name="ITF Men"/>
<sport id="2" name="Tennis"/>
```

How would I make an XML file that constantly changes it's attribute values upon a user entering an id to observe?

Answer (score 0):

Try this link. In general, you will need to get the data using jdbc and parse it in some pre defined template. 
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/tutorials/x-extract/x-extract.html